# how to access elements of string one by one

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file with hex-number like:

```
000062240
000062A4B
000062244
000062245
000062D50
00006225E
00006A25F
```

I want to read it line-by-line that would be already done pretty straight forward. Now What I want to do after reading the first line. For example `000062240`
split it in a element by element (or can be say "character by character")like

```
0 
0 
0
0
6 
2
2
4
0
```

here is the complete code but as when you use readline the return value is in string and it gives me the error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

```
import time
# code to read the file one by one and remove white space result of the readline process
fo=open('test.txt','r')

for line in fo.readlines():
 recu =  line.strip('\n')
 print recu
 for element in recu:
  print recu[element-1]
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "element" is exactly what you need, just

```html
print element
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a string "character by character" is what happens when you use `for element in recu:`

So to generate the output described, you want to simply:

```
for element in recu:
    print element
```

Outputs:

```
0
0
0
0
6
2
2
4
0
```